# Feels like it should be so simple

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to conditional format a cell (g3) to change the fill color when the following happens:

Any value in a cell in the range of g20 - g30 is greater than the value in cell j20

I must be having a brain stop, because this sounds so easy to do.

Comment: Welcome! Do you mean `=MAX($G$20:$G$30)>$J$20` ?

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Select the **G3**- go to **Home**- **Conditional Formatting**- **New Rule...**- **Use a fromula to determine which cells to format**- enter the formula `=SUMPRODUCT(($G$20:$G$29>$I$20)*1)>=1` and set the cell format(fill color):
[image]

[image]

[image]